# Insert into SQL table with two foreign keys from Temporary table data

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, sql-insert

I have a table **Hub**:

[image]

and second table **Rates**:

[image]

In this, `FromHubId` and `ToHubId` are foreign keys from `Hub` table
I wanna add some data from a file in `Rates` table. What I have tried so far is:
 Create a temp Table and insert values in it:

```
CREATE TABLE #Table
(FromHub varchar(30),
ToHub varchar(30),
Rate float,
rate40 float,
)

INSERT INTO #Table values('AUCKLAND','AUCKLAND',229.157325588818,341.973239724851),
('AUCKLAND','BLENHEIM',1825.03244430479,2738.13624934331),
('AUCKLAND','CHRISTCHURCH',1977.80399469734,2966.11840915988),
('AUCKLAND','DUNEDIN',2280.99676393793,3422.08272879301),
('AUCKLAND','GREYMOUTH',2432.59314855822,3650.06488860958),
('BLENHEIM','AUCKLAND',1520.66450929195,2280.99676393793),
('BLENHEIM','BLENHEIM',229.157325588818,341.973239724851),
('CHRISTCHURCH','AUCKLAND',1748.64666910852,2622.97000366278),
('CHRISTCHURCH','DUNEDIN',911.92863926627,1367.89295889941),
('CHRISTCHURCH','GREYMOUTH',685.121645221953,1028.27005071905),
:
:
:;
```

Create another Temp Table and trying to insert values in it:

```
CREATE TABLE #Table1
(FromHubId uniqueidentifier,
ToHubId uniqueidentifier,
Rate float,
Rate40 float,
FromHub varchar(30),
ToHub varchar(30)
);

insert into #Table1
select h.HubId As FromHubId, h.HubId As ToHubId, t.Rate, t.Rate40, t.FromHub, t.ToHub
FROM #Table t JOIN Hub h ON
t.FromHub=h.Centre and t.ToHub=h.Centre;

select * from #Table1;
```

But, It only insert values where FromHub and ToHub are same. I want to insert all values i.e. for different From and To hub as well.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks..!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TRY THIS:** you have to join separately fro both `from` and `to` hubId using table `alias` as below:

```
INSERT INTO #Table1
SELECT DISTINCT h.HubId As FromHubId, 
    h1.HubId As ToHubId, 
    t.Rate, 
    t.Rate40, 
    t.FromHub, 
    t.ToHub
FROM #Table t 
JOIN #Hub h ON t.FromHub=h.Centre 
JOIN #Hub h1 ON t.ToHub=h1.Centre;
```

Comment: @Suraj, Thanks it worked but there are some repeat entries like Auckland to Auckland 4 times?

Comment: Use `DISTINCT`, as I have just added in my query.

Comment: There are still repeated entries but different than before

Comment: I hope that's not repeated but combination from the `#Table`. It would be my pleasure if you can provide complete `#Table` data to check out this problem, if it really exists

Comment: You can try with data i already provided for that #Table has 10 rows but it inserts 19 rows in #Table1. may be because we are joining separately for same values as well Thanks

Comment: My query is tested on your given data and it's returning 10records in total with combination of from and to Hub and no any one is duplicate.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154287/discussion-between-preet-and-suraz).